# Change all varchar date formats with a single query

Tags: mysql, date-format

```
|date(varchar) |
|--------------|
|2016-02-16    |
| -------------|
|03-12-2015    |
|--------------|
|07-07-2007    |
|--------------|
|2016-03-14    |
```

Dates are stored in different formats and type is `varchar`. How to change all formats with single query in MySQL?

The formats are `d/m/y`, `d-m-y`, and `y/m/d`.

I need to copy these to a new column in date format `y-m-d`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create the new column as type `DATE`.

Then run 3 queries, one for each conversion needed.  Sure, they could be combined into a single query, but why bother; it just makes it more complex and likely to break.

And finally drop the old column and rename the new on into place?

The queries would be something like:

```
ALTER TABLE add COLUMN new_date DATE;
UPDATE tbl SET new_date = STR_TO_DATE(date,'%d-%m-%Y') WHERE substring(date,3,1) = '-';
UPDATE tbl SET new_date = STR_TO_DATE(date,'%d/%m/%Y') WHERE substring(date,3,1) = '/';
UPDATE tbl SET new_date = STR_TO_DATE(date,'%Y/%m/%d') WHERE substring(date,5,1) = '-';
```

Then do a `SELECT` to see if any rows still have a `DEFAULT` value for `new_date`;

Comment: can you please share the queries for conversion.Thanks

Comment: added some suggested SQL

Answer (score 0):

I do understand You are trying to convert to some date/time data type. All You need then is CASE expression in Your query.

This should work then - assuming that those 3 variants are the only ones occurring, and that there are no additional leading or trailing whitespace characters.

Improving this case expression to include other variants should be rather easy though:

```
CASE date
    WHEN substring(date,3,1) = '-' THEN STR_TO_DATE (date,'%d-%m-%Y')
    WHEN substring(date,3,1) = '/' THEN STR_TO_DATE (date,'%d/%m/%Y')
ELSE STR_TO_DATE (date,'%Y/%m/%d') END
```